# What are the use cases for god Cyclius, Spirit of Ages?

Tags: cookie-clicker

Here's Cyclius, Spirit of Ages:

[image: Cyclius' smug mug and not-so-smug tooltip in Cookie Clicker]

Cyclius' effect is:

> CpS bonus fluctuating between +15% and -15% over time.

and the only thing his placement in Pantheon (Diamond/Ruby/Emerald slot) changes, is how fast that fluctuation cycles (every 3/12/24 hours, respectively).

All other gods directly increase cookie production (CpS/milk/wrinkler bonuses) or enable you to do so (Golden/Wrath cookie bonuses, discounts). However, even looking at [Pantheon's page on Cookie Clicker's wikia](http://cookieclicker.wikia.com/wiki/Pantheon), the net effect of Cyclius on CpS is 0%.

What am I missing? Is Cyclius supposed to be a god you have to constantly monitor and unslot before negative bonus cycles over?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cyclius' bonus is affected by the current time of day, not how long it has been since you slotted him. So the way to use him is by slotting him when he's providing a positive bonus, and unslotting him when he's providing a negative bonus.

Comment: Well, my interpretation of his effect was way off. Thank you.

Comment: imagine the guy who is in the time zone where it remains positive for the entire time for day (using the thing where it cycles over 24 hours.) he must think its great!

Comment: Couldn't you also buy stocks when CPS is way down, then sell when your CPS is up? Seems like a potential major exploit if so

Comment: @C.Tewalt Both the question and the answer were written before Stock Market was added to the game. You make a good point - relative difference between 115% and 85% CpS is slightly over 35%. And in the 3-hour window stocks *shouldn't* fluctuate enough to override the bonus. You should probably test that out and put it in a new answer, or edit it into this one if you're sure.